# How to use jolt specification to change mongodb output?

Tags: json, mongodb, jolt

I've Mongodb JSON output as following,which I want to transform using JOLT.Can any of you suggest the JOLT specification to get the expected output.I've to remove $ character from keys.

```
Input:{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f97fbb5a00ed54b108a61ea"
    },
    "date": {
        "$date": 3808546256000
    },
    "name": "duplicate"
}
Expected Output:{
    "_id": {
        "oid": "5f97fbb5a00ed54b108a61ea"
    },
    "date": {
        "date": 3808546256000
    },
    "name": "duplicate"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "_id": {
        "\\$oid": "_id.oid"
      },
      "date": {
        "\\$date": "date.date"
      },
      "name": "name"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks.It worked.If I've to get the output as {
    "_id": "5f97fbb5a00ed54b108a61ea",
    "date": 3808546256000,
    "name": "duplicate"
} what should be the specification?

Comment: Simple.. Replace these two lines `"\\$oid": "_id"` and `"\\$date": "date"`  in the above spec.